# Populating a tableviewcontroller that is an "initial view" with data from firebase

Tags: swift, tableview

I'm a bit uncertain how to best handle this.
In my xcode project the tableviewcontroller is the initial view. And it is populated with data from firebase.
I'm using a singleton as my model and when my app starts a function "readInFirebase" populates an array that ends up being the datasource for the tableviewcontroller.

But obviously if there is a lot of data to read in - or there is a slow internet connection - the tableviewcontroller will appear empty when it loads because firebase hasn't finished reading in yet.

I was wondering how people handle this. Do I just have UIActivityIndicator overlying the tableviewcontroller until the data is populated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either have a `completion handler` for this and start a `UIActivityIndicator` when you start getting the data. When you get a callback from completion handler, then you stop the `UIActivityIndicator`.

If you want to take this even further you could just fetch a part of the data and then when the user scrolls down you fetch more data. In this way there will not be a lot of waiting and loading time for the user.

Comment: Hi Rashwan. Thanks. I have the readInFirebase function in my model, not actually in the ViewController. And the readInFirebase function is being called when my app initially loads up - readInFirebase isn't executed from the TableViewControler. So I need to tell the TableViewController when the readInFirebase from the model has finished. Is it just easier to put the readInFirebase function in the TableViewController?

Comment: I have not used `readInFirebase`, but I would have the same structure as you have now but again I have not used it before and don´t know how it works.

Comment: Hi @Rashwan. I have that all working. I have a completion handler and in my TableViewController when firebase loading finishes i'm notified. But the issue i'm having now is how to reload the table data.   model.readInFirebaseData { (success) in
            ("done")
        }
           
            
        //     activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
          dataList = model.dataArray  
          self.tableView.reloadData()
            
        }    ...... tableView.reloadData() isn't doing anything. But if I segue to a different screen and come back the TableView is populated.

Comment: @Mike, do this in your `viewWillAppear` and see if it makes any difference for you.